# how to get the array size in ms excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, automatic-update, array

I would like to write a formula which returns the size of an array. something like

```
size(A1:A50)
```

Maybe, it seems to be strange; but it helps me when I insert some new rows in the first 50 lines and my formula updates automatically; but if I wrote 50 instead of (let say) size(A1:A50), it would not update automatically and it makes problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest answer is the [`ROWS`](http://support.office.microsoft.com/client/ROWS-function-20308b39-36cd-4d8a-a2f8-3e4ac6542f32?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&NS=EXCEL&Version=14&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60124&CorrelationId=5caaf1c3-4196-4af1-a2c7-5b61af0b41a7) function: `ROWS(A1:A50)` is `50`.